# Can ";" be used interchangeably with "|" and ":"?

Tags: notation, game-theory

I know that "|" and ":" are both used to create sets and are read as "such that".

I now encountered ";". Since I didn't know its meaning, so I looked it up on wikipedia, where it says that it can be used interchangeably with the other two.

The problem is, this doesn't make much sense when I apply it to the example where I read it, namely the definition of a bayesian nash equilibria:

$$\sum_{t_{-i}\in T_{-i}}p_i(t_{-i}|t_i)u_i(s_i^*(t_i),s_{-i}^*(t_{-i});t_i)\geq \sum_{t_{-i}\in T_{-i}}p_i(t_{-i}|t_i)u_i(a_i,s_{-i}^*(t_{-i});t_i)$$

It just doesn't make sense to change notation style within one definition, right?

Could you tell me how I should read the ";" here?

Comment: I would look up an earlier definition where the notation is used. Your way of reading those symbols is the predominant way they're used in set-theory; however, in a different branch, it could be used differently. I've seen a semi-colon used in multi-variable calculus when a comma is undesirable.

Comment: I agree with @RobertWolfe.  Here the ; sign is used as a kind of comma, separating the first two arguments  (which are of one kind) of the function $u$ from the third, which is evidently a different kind of argument.  The $|$ sign is also used here as a kind of comma in an argument list of a function.